# Unable to load/display GUI Window

Tags: python, squish

Followed steps mentioned in squish website,

https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/semi-automatic-testing/

1. Downloaded and copied easygui.py and choicebox.py in test suite folder.
2. Copied below script in test.py,

   import subprocess

   def main():
   c = choicebox("Message", "Title", ["Choice 1", "Choice 2"])
   test.log(c)

   def choicebox(msg, title, choices_array):
   cmd = ["python"]
   cmd.append(squishinfo.testCase + "/../choicebox.py")
   cmd.append(msg)
   cmd.append(title)
   for c in choices_array:
   cmd.append(c)

   ```
   s = os_capture(cmd)

   # Return first line, on all platforms
   s = s.replace("\r\n", "\n")
   s = s.replace("\r", "\n")
   return s.split("\n")[0]
   ```

   def os_capture(cmd):
   return subprocess.Popen(
   args=cmd,
   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate()[0]

Above code took from squish website to create the GUI display/window.

When i run above script file,

My squish control bar is keep running,

No window/GUI window is displayed.There is no output.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use the [testInteraction](https://doc.qt.io/squish/squish-api.html#testinteraction-functions) functions provided by Squish instead.

PS: The knowledge base article that you mentioned had some issues that should be fixed by now. However, the article itself is deprecated now, in favor of the testInteraction functions.